# Click an element with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to **scrape** this page:

https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/tournamentEvent?tournamentEventId=4073

And I want to click in every blue stats icon (there is one for every match of the tournament)

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

URL = "https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/tournamentEvent?tournamentEventId=4073"
driver.get(URL)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
cookies = driver.find_element_by_id("cookiesNotification")
cookies.click()
# Trying to click the cookies

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "matchStats-171140")))
element.click()
```

This is the answer that I get:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a...id="matchStats-171140" href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xxs glyphicon glyphicon-stats" onclick="showMatchStats(171140, event, false)" title="Match Statistics"> </a> is not clickable at point (880, 566). Other element would receive the click: <div id="cookiesNotification" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 100; text-align: center; background-color: indigo; color: wheat; opacity: 0.9; padding: 10px;">...</div>
```

I tried clicking the cookies's button but it didn't work...

The output I want, e.g. by clicking on the finals, should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klxi7.png)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript executor to click on Accept cookies button:-

```
WebElement acceptCookieButton = driver.findElement(By.linkText("OK, I agree"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", acceptCookieButton);
```

Once, cookie is accepted, all your web elements will be clickable.